# Coordinate transform a triangle

Tags: geometry, transformation, coordinate-systems

There is a triangle with points `P1(x1,y1)`,`P2(x2,y2)`,`P3(x3,y3)` on an XY plane.

The final position after transformation are known to us, `P1'(x,y)` and `P2'(x,y)`
How can I find the third point?

Using slope (or distance) formula gives two solutions (one is mirror image of another). Assuming the transformation is a combination of translation and rotation, how do I get the new coordinates of the final point `P3'` ?

Comment: $\vec{P_1P_2}=\vec{P_1'P_2'}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
\begin{align}
u &= (a, b) = (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1)\\
v &= (c, d) = (x_2' - x_1', y_2' - y_1').
\end{align}
be the vectors from $P_1$ to $P_2$ and from $P_1'$ to $P_2'$, respectively.

Then $u$ and $v$ should have the same length; let that length be
$$
s = \sqrt{u_x^2 + u_y ^2 }.
$$

Also define
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\up}{u^\perp}
\newcommand{\vp}{v^\perp}
\up &= (-b, a)\\
\vp &= (-d, c)
\end{align}
 Finally, let 
$$
w = (x_3 - x_1, y_3 - y_1)
$$
be the vector from $P_1$ to $P_3$.

Then compute
$$
p = w \cdot u \\
q = w \cdot \up
$$
and build the vector
$$
w' = \frac{1}{s^2} (p v + q \vp)
$$
Then 
$$
P_3' = P_1' + w'.
$$

If the "dot product" used above doesn't isn't familiar to you, it just means this: the dot product of two vectors $(e, f)$ and $(g, h)$ is just the number $eg+fh$.

Actually, let me just write out the answer as best I can, trying to avoid typos. The $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $P_3'$ are computed like this:

\begin{align}
p &= (x_3 - x_1)(x_2 - x_1) + (y_3 - y_1)(y_2 - y_1) \\
q &= -(x_3 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1) + (y_3 - y_1)(x_2 - x_1) \\
x_3' &= x_1' + \frac{1}{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2} \left( p(x_2' - x_1') - q (y_2' - y_1') \right)\\
y_3' &= y_1' + \frac{1}{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2} \left( p(y_2' - y_1') + q (x_2' - x_1') \right)
\end{align}
Notice the negative sign in front of the first term in the formula for $q$, and the difference in the last two parts of the formulas for $x_3'$ and $y_3'$ (the first has a minus; the second has a plus).